# Why App shortcuts are not working android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shortcut

I had implemented the app shortcuts as per the android developer website but it is resulting in nothing.
App shortcuts are not being showing up.

Here is

shortcuts.xml

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="sleeptimer"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/sleep_timer_short"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/sleep_timer_long"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/sleep_timer_long">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.vikaskonaparthi.cronus"
        android:targetClass="com.vikaskonaparthi.cronus.activities.SleepTimerActivity" />
    <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
         here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
         they launch this shortcut. -->
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.timer" />
</shortcut>
<!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

Here is what I had done in Mainfest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
        android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.....................

Comment: Your <meta-data> must be wrapped in the activity whose intent filters are set to the android.intent.action.MAIN action and the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER.

Comment: Wow thanks that solve my issue

Comment: I have the same problem. When I deploy the app to my physical device it's not working. When I deploy to Android Automotive OS emulator it's working.